# Magento, how to add static url link in Block

Tags: html, css, xml, magento

I am stuck at adding a url link in block programmatically, I need to add a URL to customized page which edited under CMS/page and I want to add it in .xml file by adding something like below.

```
<action method="addLink" 
        translate="label title" 
        module="catalog">
        <label>My Account</label>
        <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" />
        <title>My Account</title>
</action>
```

Above sample retrieve url from module, but no idea what are the parameters should be used for static CMS/page url. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me take an example of top.links block to explain this.

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

The “addLink” function is defined in Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links. The definition of the function is

```
public function addLink($label, $url='', $title='', $prepare=false, $urlParams=array(),
        $position=null, $liParams=null, $aParams=null, $beforeText='', $afterText='')
```

Also the phtml file where the html code for this is written is ‘page/template/links.phtml’.

```
<reference name="top.links">
     <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link">
         <action method="addWishlistLink"></action>
     </block>
 </reference>
```

Answer to your question is pretty simple.

Suppose we need to add a new link to top links, lets say a link for a CMS page called Terms and Conditions. To do this open a layout file, let say customer.xml and add the below code:

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Terms and Condition</label>
    <url>terms</url>
    <title>Terms and Condition</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare>
    <position>2</position>
  </action>
</reference>
</default>
```

Comment: if the value of url is terms, then the full path of this one is www.XXX.com/index.php/terms? besides, what's usage of translate field in action define?

Comment: When you see translate="label" module="customer", this tells Magento that it should pass the value in the <label> tag through the customer module's data helper's translate method before displaying it to the screen. In over simplified terms

$label_value = (string) $node->label;
echo Mage::helper('customer')->__($label_value);

If the module attribute is not present, the core module is used.